# Unclickable Seekbar in android listview

Tags: android

I have a Listview in my application. Listview rows are clickable. I have introduced a seek bar in each row of a Listview. Despite settings android:clickable="false" for Seekbar in layout xml, I am still able to click on it and move seek bar as desired. I don't want Seekbar to be clickbale but I do want Listview row to clickable.

Any pointers will be appreciated.

Here's my layout file

```
android:progressDrawable="@drawable/slider_range"
        android:thumb="@drawable/slider_thumb"
        android:layout_width="80dip"
        android:layout_height="12dip"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:longClickable="false"
```

Comment: any luck in finding an answer?

Answer (score 12):

```
seekBarObj.setOnSeekBarChangeListener( new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        int originalProgress;

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            //Nothing here..                
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            originalProgress = seekBar.getProgress();
        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int arg1, boolean fromUser) {
            if( fromUser == true){
                seekBar.setProgress( originalProgress);
            }               
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the enabled attribute to false. You may have to manually adjust the color if you want to avoid it appearing "*greyed out"*

e.g.

```
seekBar.setEnabled(false);
```

I've now got this working using both setFocusable and setEnabled to false, I've implemented a solution to enable the seekbar for a single adjustment when the list item is clicked too if you are interested.

Comment: Only thing that worked for me , thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Add focusable=false to the seekbar.