# seekbar.setEnabled(false) make seekbar invisible

Tags: java, android, seekbar, mobile-development

I have problem with seekbar. I want to make it disable, but when I use .setEnabled(false) function my seekbar disappear. How to avoid this?

My layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorBackground">

    <SeekBar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/seekBar"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

My code:

```
  SeekBar seekBar=(SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
  seekBar.setEnabled(false);
```

Comment: I am not sure `setEnable(false)` made seekbar disappear. you should post your layout/code, so other dev can help you.

Comment: I edit my post. This is my code. After this my seekbar is invisible, but I want only make it disable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still dont't know why my seekbar disappear but I find another way to disable a seekBar here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3278613/4313791